# Docker copy a file from host to Container?

Tags: docker

How to copy a file from host to a Docker Container?
 Docker cp is used to copy from container to host but I am not getting any option to copy from host to Container

Answer (score 3):

First, if you need to make this sort of change, it generally suggests that you need to rethink the architecture of your containers.  Options to consider are (a) providing the file at build time via COPY comands in your Dockerfile, or (b) mounting a host directory into your container when you start it, and using that to transfer files in/out.

That said, you could probably arrange to use something like `docker exec` to get a file into a container:

```
docker exec -i mycontainer sh -c 'cat > /path/to/destination' < /path/to/source
```

Comment: thanks .I also find a different way to copy the file to Docker container running on EC2 using sftp

Answer (score 2):

`Docker cp` can be used to copy file from container to host, and host to container as well.

Conteiner to host: `sudo docker cp da9230faeb38:/file ./`

Host to container: `sudo docker cp Desktop/file da9230faeb38:/`